# getting error 0x8002802f during ms office 2010 installation

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I'm trying to install MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate, but installation end up with following error code `0x8002802f`.

Comment: 0x8002802f = TYPE_E_DLLFUNCTIONNOTFOUND (Function not defined in specified DLL). Maybe a Windows DLL is corrupted Run **sfc /scannow**.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have .NET FrameWork installed. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Another Workaround

Before you install Office 2010 SP1, put a readable DVD or CD into your optical drive, or connect a USB drive. Any should do.

Comment: Not helpful.Now, I'm getting some rubbish error saying **To install this product you must have Windows 7/Vista/XP** OS